# Change color from a given date?

Tags: r, plot, radix

I have this plot and I need to change the color of the line from observation 2,000 onwards to color red. I have done it using ggplot and it's quite easy but I'd like to do it using Base R. I have been reading some posts but I haven't figured out exactly how I should do this.

So this is it, having part of the plot in blue and the other in red.

I'd really appreciate any advice or recommendation!
 [image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

You provided no data, so I can only assume. Here a solution using the base R `plot` function:

```
# some data
set.seed(123)
d <-runif(3000, 0, 2)
d[sample(1:3000, 2800)] <- 0 # set some zero values

# A color vector
COL <- c(rep(1, 2000), rep(2, length(d)))
# and the plot using the histogram option:
plot(d, type="h", col=COL)
```

As you said that the "h" function is not an appropriate tool, you can also use a `loop` and `lines`:

```
plot(d, type="n")
for(i in 1:length(d)){
   M <- cbind(c(i, i), c(d[i], 0)) # Matrix of start and end points of the line
   lines(M, col=COL[i])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works if I use the histogram option. I'm using the line option. It is an adjusted time series of hourly data of messages sent using a mobile app i (I can't post the data). So I guess it is not exactly the same the histogram and the line for this purpose.

Comment: @adrian1121 Try to build a dataset looking like yours or exchange the values. I think the color is not working with a vector using the "l" option. I edited also my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a litte bother to change lines() colour, I used segments() making duplicated end point data.

```
# make a sample data
df <- data.frame(ind = 1:200, y = runif(200, 0, 10))

#  combine df and df shifting one row
df <- cbind(df, rbind(df, c(NA, NA))[-1,])

plot(df[,1:2], type="n")         # (edit) using Mr.Pereira's code, thanks.
segments(df[,1], df[,2], df[,3], df[,4], col = ifelse( df[,1] < 150, "blue", "red"))
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(ind = 1:5000, y = runif(5000, 0, 10))


plot(df$y, type="h", col= ifelse( df$ind < 2000, "blue", "red"))
```

[image]